# How to compute with Core Data

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to make a small program that keeps count of the amount of times pressed on a button. I'm using Core Data to store the information. The only problem is that I can't figure out how to compute with the information in the core data. If someone can tell me how to make a variable in the code equal to the value of the information in the Core Data I know enough.
If there is another way to compute with the Core Data I would like to know about.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext



    /*let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Data", into: context)

    newUser.setValue(number, forKey: "number")

    do{
        try context.save()
        print("Saved")
    }catch{
        print("Error occured in the saving process.")
    }*/




    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Data")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do{
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0{
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]{

                if let number = result.value(forKey: "number") as? Double{
                    print("number is ", number)
                result.setValue(number + 1, forKey: "number")
                        do{
                            try context.save()
                        }catch{

                }
            }
            }
        }
    }catch{
        print("Error with fetching data.")
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

var number = 0.0

}
```

The error it's given on the line with nummer = number += 1:
Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'Double'

I appreciate all of your answers.

Comment: It's highly recommended to use an `NSManagedObject` subclass. If you want to do math with `Double` you have to declare `var number = 0.0` with a floating point literal, because an literal `0` declares the variable as `Int`, and – however it's not mandatory – use floating point literals in the other lines, too, to indicate that you are dealing with `Double`s. By the way `results.count >= 0` is nonsense, `results` is always 0 or more. To check if the array is not empty use `!results.isEmpty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Core Data. This line doesn't make sense:

```
nummer = nummerVar += 1
```

The `+=` operator increases `nummerVar` in place. You're assigning this to `number`, but the **return value** of the `+=` operation is not a `Double`, so you can't assign it to a `Double`.

I'm not completely sure what you intended here. You might have meant

```
nummer = nummerVar + 1
```

Or maybe you meant

```
nummerVar += 1
nummer = nummerVar
```

Either of those are valid code, but which one you need depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! You're totally right. I just had to use a + sign instead of +=. I will edit the code to the right code.